# How can I make the part of the past cone transparent, so that the picture looks 3d?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, transparent

I recently started with tikz and I am absolutely clueless how I can make the labeled part transparent! I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{80}{45}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-90}{180}{-90}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering

 \tikzset{surface/.style={draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!40!white, fill opacity=.6}}

 \newcommand{\coneback}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:225+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \newcommand{\conefront}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:-135+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, grid/.style={help lines,blue!40!white,opacity=0.2},scale=1]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
   \fill[blue!40!white,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4,0) -- (-4,4,0) -- (4,4,0) -- (4,-4,0) -- cycle;
  
   \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
     \foreach \y in {-4,...,4}
     {
         \draw[grid] (\x,-4) -- (\x,4);
         \draw[grid] (-4,\y) -- (4,\y);
     }
   \coneback[surface]{-3}{2}{-12}
   \conefront[surface]{-3}{2}{-12}
   \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) {};
   \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) {};
   \coneback[surface]{3}{2}{12}
   \draw[-,dashed] (0,0,-2.65) -- (0,0,2.65) node[above] {};
   \draw[-,dashed] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,-3.35) node[above] {};
   \draw[->,dashed] (0,0,3.35) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$time$};
   \conefront[surface]{3}{2}{12}
   \fill (4,0,2) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$C$};
   \fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt) {};
   \fill (-0.5,-0.85,2.2) circle (2pt) node[above left] {$A$};
   \fill (1.3,0.5,2) circle (2pt) node[above left] {$B$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,2) node[below, pos=0.6, rotate=26.5651,scale=0.70,black] {$\textbf{spacelike vector}$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (1.3,0.5,2) node[below, pos=0.65, rotate=55.1459,scale=0.70,black] {$\textbf{lightlike vector}$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (-0.5,-0.85,2.2) node[above, pos=0.57, rotate=-65.8557,scale=0.70,black] {$\textbf{timelike vector}$};
   \node[black] at (0,0,3) {$Future\,\,Light\,\,Cone$};
   \node[black] at (0,0,-3) {$Past\,\,Light\,\,Cone$};
   \node[black] at (0,0.05,0.3) {$O$};
   \node[black] at (0,4.7,0) {$space$};
   \node[black] at (5,-0.3,0) {$space$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Light Cone in 2d Space plus a Time Dimension}
 \label{cone}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `[opacity=.5]` will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the lower cone first. Then draw the plane, and then the upper cone. Changing the color scheme can help too, since the blue on blue makes it harder to see what's in front. You can outline the plane to give additional contrast. Lastly, I would split up the time axis so that the past half is drawn before the plane.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering

 \tikzset{surface/.style={draw=blue!70!black, fill=blue!20!white, fill opacity=.6}}

 \newcommand{\coneback}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:225+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \newcommand{\conefront}[4][]{
 \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=#2, #1] (45-#4:#3) arc (45-#4:-135+#4:#3) -- (O) --cycle;
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, grid/.style={help lines,violet!40!white,opacity=0.5},scale=1]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  
     \coneback[surface]{-3}{2}{-12}
   \conefront[surface]{-3}{2}{-12} 
  
   \fill[violet!40!white,opacity=0.5] (-4,-4,0) -- (-4,4,0) -- (4,4,0) -- (4,-4,0) -- cycle;
  
   \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
     \foreach \y in {-4,...,4}
     {
         \draw[grid] (\x,-4) -- (\x,4);
         \draw[grid] (-4,\y) -- (4,\y);
         \draw[violet] (-4,4)--(-4,-4)--(4,-4)--(4,4)--cycle;
     }

   \draw[->] (-4,0,0) -- (4,0,0) {};
   \draw[->] (0,-4,0) -- (0,4,0) {};
   \coneback[surface]{3}{2}{12}
   \draw[-,dashed] (0,0,-2.65) -- (0,0,2.65) node[above] {};
   \draw[-,dashed] (0,0,-4) -- (0,0,-3.35) node[above] {};
   \draw[->,dashed] (0,0,3.35) -- (0,0,4) node[above] {$time$};
   \conefront[surface]{3}{2}{12}
   \fill (4,0,2) circle (2pt) node[above right] {$C$};
   \fill (0,0,0) circle (2pt) {};
   \fill (-0.5,-0.85,2.2) circle (2pt) node[above left] {$A$};
   \fill (1.3,0.5,2) circle (2pt) node[above left] {$B$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,2) node[below, pos=0.6, rotate=26.5651,scale=0.70,black] {$\textbf{spacelike vector}$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (1.3,0.5,2) node[below, pos=0.65, rotate=55.1459,scale=0.70,black] {$\textbf{lightlike vector}$};
   \draw[->,red] (0,0,0) -- (-0.5,-0.85,2.2) node[above, pos=0.57, rotate=-65.8557,scale=0.70,black] {$\textbf{timelike vector}$};
   \node[black] at (0,0,3) {$Future\,\,Light\,\,Cone$};
   \node[black] at (0,0,-3) {$Past\,\,Light\,\,Cone$};
   \node[black] at (0,0.05,0.3) {$O$};
   \node[black] at (0,4.7,0) {$space$};
   \node[black] at (5,-0.3,0) {$space$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Light Cone in 2d Space plus a Time Dimension}
 \label{cone}
\end{figure}
```